# Dynamic user interface creation problem 

Tags: android, user-interface, view

How  to Create dynamic user interface with events...

Hi Friends i want to create a user interface. in which i will have some buttons  and labels
but the number of buttons and lables will be changing time to time depending upon the  data retrieved from the server...

Can any one please guide me to do solve this issue... with usefuls links and guidence..

Comment: do u mean u wanna add layout object during runtime (or)
u just wanna change the text of the object dynamically

Comment: i want to create one table like view. which contains buttons and labels and i need to provide onclick event for these dynamically created buttons

Answer (score 0):

This uses two linear layouts to achieve a grid. The higher level LinearLayout is defined in linearlayout.xml, and holds element views vertically. Within each of these vertical views, a `Row` (custom LinearLayout) is instanciated, and in doing so, specifies the event handler(s). This LinearLayout holds its elements horizontally.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.linearlayout);

        ViewGroup main = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        main.addView(new Row(this));
        main.addView(new Row(this));
    }
    private class Row extends LinearLayout {
        public Row(Context context) {
            super(context);
            TextView text = new TextView(context);
            Button button = new Button(context);
            text.setText("Text");
            button.setText("Button");
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            this.addView(text);
            this.addView(button);
        }
    }
}
```

linearlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

Is this what you were looking for?